# How to recover lost soft skills>

Tags: communication, skills

I feel that my interpersonal skills could use some work.  What methods or resources do you use to brush up on your interpersonal skills if you're not a natural social butterfly?

Comment: With all due respect, I suspect that you overestimated your "finesse with dealing with people" that you supposedly had previously.

Comment: No offense, but this question is off topic for the site.  You will find a number of useful resources for building your [interpersonal skills](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=interpersonal+skills) online.

Comment: https://www.allbusiness.com/slideshow/ten-ways-to-improve-your-interpersonal-skills-15606969-1.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking at it the wrong way, if the job became toxic enough for you to quit, then your previous 'finesse' with dealing with people wasn't working too well. The workplace is a totally different environment from college, you need to acquire a different set of people skills particularly as youngster.

Mostly these are about keeping your head down and absorbing as much as you can. Dealing with arrogance and a lack of interest in your issues and lack of faith in your abilities is sometimes par for the course..

Comment: Not getting to far into detail, my last job was extended to me when oil was $100 a barrel and then a month after the price crashed.  Every single person hired in my class (10 people) felt it was toxic enough to leave as not a single one of them is still in that role.  

I will admit that my 'finesse' previously probably wasn't that good, but I would like to know what resources or exercises people have found to be helpful in building up their soft skills.  Googling listicles about 'interpersonal skills' don't help.